# Do Japanese governments support fluoridation?

Tags: policy, japan, water

Do Japanese governments support fluoridation?

Wikipedia's article on fluoridation states that [less than 1%](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoridation_by_country#Japan) of Japan receives water fluoridation. However, not all countries supply fluoride via water. From the first paragraph of the previous link:

> Artificial fluoridation of water, **salt**, and **milk** varies from
> country to country. Water fluoridation has been introduced to varying
> degrees in many countries, including Australia, Brazil, Canada, Chile,
> Ireland, Malaysia, the U.S., and Vietnam, and is used by 5.7% of
> people worldwide. Continental Europe largely does not fluoridate
> water, although some of its countries fluoridate salt; locations have
> discontinued water fluoridation in Germany, the Netherlands, and other
> countries. Health and dental organizations support water fluoridation
> in the countries that practice water fluoridation. There has been
> opposition to water fluoridation whenever it is proposed.

Do Japanese governments at any level (federal, prefectural, or local council) take any measures to either encourage or make compulsory the supply of fluoride? For example, mandating minimum fluoride levels in toothpaste or salt, or public information campaigns encouraging people to choose fluoridated toothpaste?

It's quite possible Japanese governments hasn't done anything about fluoridation. From a [pro-fluoridation site](http://waterfluoridationcenter.org/papers/2001/antifluoride.html):

> Japan
>
> Currently less than 1% of Japan has community water
> fluoridation. Dental disease in Japan is very severe compared to the
> United States.

Comment: I saw "Japan" in the title and I knew it was Andrew Grimm.

Comment: less than 1% of Japan receives water fluoridation. - that's because they don't want to [get brainwashed like Americans do](http://rense.com/general79/hd3.htm)

Comment: @DVK In case you weren't joking. That is a myth. 
http://www.politifact.com/florida/statements/2011/oct/06/critics-water-fluoridation/truth-about-fluoride-doesnt-include-nazi-myth/

Comment: @user4012 they are robbing our precious bodily fluids!Protect the purity of essence! (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove)

Answer (score 4):

I'll list some facts I've found around. My translations aren't so great but I believe you will get the gist.

> "Japan generally does not fluoridate its water supply, and Okinawa is
> no exception. However, the traditional Japanese diet does not promote
> tooth decay the way that the average American diet does, dentists
> say."
> "While most U.S. Forces Japan installations do not treat their
> municipal water, Misawa Air Base fluoridates water on its main base
> and north area with sodium fluoride, at a cost of about $6,500 per
> year, according to Maj. Monte Harner of the 35th Civil Engineer
> Squadron."

http://www.stripes.com/news/water-on-okinawa-bases-no-longer-fluoridated-1.35435

The maximum level of fluoride by the Water quality standards is 0.8ppm.
https://www.jda.or.jp/park/prevent/index05_13.html

> "Views on fluoride applications for dental caries prevention program
> in 1982 Japan oral hygiene Society Fluorine Research Group Recommend
> fluoride application it is recommended the application of fluoride for
> dental health
>
> 1. Fluorine is a need for dental health, after the formation phase and eruption of teeth, is more effective throughout life.
> 2. Application of fluoride, which is carried out in the dental health management is safe.
> 3. For the children of caries prevention, programs of public health fluoride application is effective.
> 4. Application of fluoride has been recommended internationally widely."

http://www.niph.go.jp/soshiki/koku/oralhealth/ffrg/m/kenkai1.html

Ministry of Health and Welfare Health Policy Bureau Dental Health Division and living Health Water Environment Department
consensus document of the Ministry of Health and Welfare Dental Health Division (December 6, 2000) said:

> "1)For fluoride application, including the addition of fluoride to tap
> water, you are recognized as a challenge while watching the progress
> of welfare science research, it will consider.
>
> 2)From local government, if there is a request of technical assistance
> for the addition of fluoride in the water quality standards (0.8㎎ / 1L
> below), water suppliers, water users, on the assumption the
> understanding such as local Dental Association, and the Health Science
> I want to continue depending as part of the dental health
> administration such as by utilizing the results of research."

http://www.niph.go.jp/soshiki/koku/oralhealth/ffrg/m/kenkai2.html

> "In Japan, water fluoridation have been made as a test study in Kyoto
> Yamashina district from 1952 to 1965. Any Other in Okinawa Prefecture
> (1957-73 years) and Mie Prefecture Asahi-machi (1967-72 years) may
> have been carried out. Both unfortunately now has been discontinued,
> but it is where the resume is desired."

http://www.e-healthnet.mhlw.go.jp/information/teeth/h-02-010.html

But looks like instead of water fluoridation, Japan promotes fluoridated mouthwash.

> "To "health promotion 8020 promotion regulations of Hokkaido
> tooth-mouth", which came into effect in June 2009, the promotion of
> fluoride mouthwash in elementary and junior high schools as an
> effective dental health measures have been incorporated. For dental
> caries prevention of students of the main road in Hokkaido Board of
> Education, and we are actively promoting the fluoride mouthwash in
> school."

http://www.dokyoi.pref.hokkaido.lg.jp/hk/ktk/hukkabutu.htm
http://www.fukushihoken.metro.tokyo.jp/iryo/iryo_hoken/shikahoken/pamphlet/susumeyoufukkabutsuouyou.html